# Unable to Mock CLBeacon using OCMock

Tags: ios, ibeacon, cllocation, ocmock

I'm trying to mock the CLBeacon object inorder to test the app behavior for a particular type of beacon. But I'm facing trouble to stub the method proximity to return a required proximity value from it.

Below is the code which has the issue:

```
id clBeacon = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[CLBeacon class]];

[[[clBeacon stub] andReturn:@"2"] major];
[[[clBeacon stub] andReturn:@"0"] minor];

[[[clBeacon stub] andReturnValue: OCMOCK_VALUE(CLProximityNear)] proximity]; // Didn't work

[[[clBeacon stub] andReturn: @""] proximity]; // Didn't work
```

The above code raising the below issue when I'm trying to stub the proximity response.

```
Multiple methods named 'proximity' found with mismatched result, parameter or attributes
```

Can someone point me the exact issue with the above code??

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

the proximity property is not a string but rather a CLProximity typedef.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CLProximity) {
    CLProximityUnknown,
    CLProximityImmediate,
    CLProximityNear,
    CLProximityFar
} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Try something like this:

```
[[[clBeacon stub] andReturn: @(CLProximityImmediate)] proximity]; // Didn't work
```

You should also pass in NSNumber objects for the major and minor values instead of strings as well

---

**Edit:**

Have you also tried doing something like this:

```
id clBeacon = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[CLBeacon new]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured where the actual issue is.

So, I've two other classes which has proximity property but with different type (One is CLProximity and the other is NSString), so it is having conflict in choosing the right one.

Comment: You should be able to do something like `[(CLBeacon *)[[clBeacon stub] andReturnValue: OCMOCK_VALUE(CLProximityNear)] proximity];` to tell the compiler which one you mean.  The return type from stub etc. is `id`, which could be any object, which avoids compiler complaints of unknown messages sent to OCMockObject if it was typed that way instead.  But with "id", if the compiler finds the same method name but with different return types, it doesn't know how to set up the frame thus its error.  It needs to be told which one.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare using `CLBeacon` instead of `id`.

`CLBeacon *clBeacon = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[CLBeacon class]];`